# Split video in iOS from NSDocument directory

Tags: iphone, ios, video

I'm trying to read a video from NSDocument Directory and split it to 1 minute. I've been trying to use ALAssetsLibrary but not able to work with that as I do not get ReferenceURL for the video stored in NSDocuments Directory.

Can anyone suggest me a workaround for this?

Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: `ALAssetsLibrary` is only for images and videos in the users photos.app not for your own files.

Comment: Right. Then what is the workaround for this if I need to do it for videos in NSDocument Directory?

Comment: There is none, since it is not meant for that.

Answer (score 0):

with the use of this code you'll be able to find your video url

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/vid1.mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempPath];
```